# What are the use cases for "Keep Disk Names" and "Keep Hardware UUIDs" when cloning a VirtualBox vm?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, clone

The [dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/clone.html) that comes up when one clones a VirtualBox VM has two checkboxes, labeled "Keep Disk Names" and "Keep Hardware UUIDs".  The documentation for these options is as follows

- ***Keep Disk Names:*** Retains the disk image names when cloning the VM.
- ***Keep Hardware UUIDs:*** Retains the hardware universally unique identifiers (UUIDs) when cloning the VM.

Based on this, I cannot figure out under what conditions I would want to specify either option.

**Q:** What are the typical use cases for either?

(The two use cases I am most interested in are: back-up and copying a VM to a different host.  In case it matters, I work primarily on Linux hosts, and Linux, OpenBSD, and Windows 10 guests.)

Comment: I believe it has to do with Licensing requirements. If you make it an exact clone (same data) and move it to another machine, VBOX may ask you about the. VMware asks me if I moved or copied the machine. If I select copy it will try to activate in the case of Windows. Linux does not matter.

Comment: @John: Thanks!  "> ...VBOX may ask you about the." ???  Ask you about the what?

Comment: I think virtualizing apps use roughly the same overall method for controlling clones. Otherwise it would be too easy to copy machines and evade licensing (Windows).